# Pyspark Naive Bayes using fit in batches

Tags: python, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to train a Naive Bayes Classifer on a Large Database (30GB).
Due to memory limitations i have to split the DB query in to multiple batches.

I am using a Pipeline as seen here :

```
categoryIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="diff", outputCol="label")
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="raw")
remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="raw", outputCol="words")
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="features",  numFeatures=100000)
nb = NaiveBayes(smoothing=1.0, modelType="multinomial")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[categoryIndexer, tokenizer, remover, hashingTF, nb])
```

and then using a fit inside of a for loop.

```
for i in range(0,365):
    df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=url,table="(SELECT text, diff FROM tweets INNER JOIN djitf ON tweets.created = djitf.day WHERE id > "+ str(i*1000000)+ "AND id <"+ str((i+1)*1000000)+") as table1", properties=properties)
    train_data, test_data = df.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
    model = pipeline.fit(train_data)
```

However my results suggest that the model is overwritten every time I call the fit function on the pipeline. How can I keep the already fitted data, and just add to it?

Is there a parameter or something im missing? For example in Sklearn there is the `partial_fit` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no missing parameter. Spark doesn't support incremental fit and it shouldn't be required. Spark can easily process larger than memory data, possibly with on-disk caching. If 30GB of data is still to much for your resources then you shouldn't use Spark at all.

If the problem is just on read use predicates:

```
predicates = [
    "id > {0} AND id < {1}".format(i * 1000000, (i + 1) * 1000000)
    for i in range(0, 365)
]

df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(
    url=url,
    table="""(SELECT text, diff 
               FROM tweets INNER 
               JOIN djitf ON tweets.created = djitf.day") as table1""", 
     predicates=predicates,
     properties=properties)
```

or ranges for JDBC reader:

```
df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(
    url=url,
    table="""(SELECT cast(id, INTEGER), text, diff 
               FROM tweets INNER 
               JOIN djitf ON tweets.created = djitf.day") as table1""",
    column="id", lowerBound=0, upperBound=366 * 1000000, numPartitions=300)
```